# xrandr - is laptop display always "eDP-1"

Tags: 22.04, xorg, display, monitor, xrandr

I want to write myself some help scripts targeting the laptop monitor
and I want to make it generic.

I've noticed that on 3 different laptops with Ubuntu 22 the laptop display is always marked in `xrandr` as "**eDP-1**".

Is this always the case?

If not - what are the conditions that affect this generated display name?

I found somewhere that eDP should mean "embedded display port" so I would assume that if the laptop doesn't have more embedded display ports, it will be always marked as `eDP-1`. But then I found this question - [eDP-1-1 to eDP-1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1324257/edp-1-1-to-edp-1) - for Ubuntu 20 and this archive https://lists.x.org/archives/xorg/2017-March/058634.html that mentions "eDP-1-1" in the initial state - which worries me a bit. I also failed to find the documentation describing what eDP means and what are the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't always be that way. On my laptop, for example, it is `eDP1` not `eDP-1`. And, anyway, I imagine it is possible for laptops, especially older ones, to use something other than Display Port. However, there is no need for this. You can rely on the laptop's screen being the first output. For instance, I have a script I use to toggle between different screen setups, and I use:

```
screens=( $(xrandr | awk '$2=="connected"{print $1}') )
laptopScreen=${screens[0]}
```

And then just use `"$laptopScreen"` anywhere I would use `eDP1`.

Comment: Interesting, is first even when it's turned off. Is this documented somewhere? Note for others: `xrandr --listmonitors` does *not* include the display when turned off unless appended with `--verbose`

Comment: @jave.web yes, at least in my case. Even turned off, it is still connected so it is returned first.

Comment: I think the answer is sufficient, but if you would find some official documentation links proving how the generation works that would be nice :-)

Comment: Sorry, @jave.web, I wouldn't even know where to start looking.